# Why thermodynamic state variables of a sytem are only defined at thermodynamic equilibrium and not during any other instant?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

As you have read the title so my question is why are thermodynamic variables only meaningful when the thermodynamic system is in thermodynamic equilibrium and is always meaningless in any other case.

Comment: I disagree with the premise. The Gibbs free energy is still the Gibbs free energy whether the system is in equilibrium or not. And the difference between non-equilibrium and equilibrium is the driving force to get to equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

Variables such as T and p are not well-defined when a system is fluctuating. Thermodynamic state variables are defined for systems that are static or quasi-static (in the latter case, transitioning very slowly - and therefore reversibly - through a series of equilibrium points). The main reason is that macroscopic fluctuations are absent in true equilibrium states. Each phase in such states is homogeneous. The argument is thus somewhat circular: thermodynamic states are homogeneous states that have fixed properties. The only way to guarantee fixed properties is by being at equilibrium.

Note that it is possible to obtain thermodynamic parameters by imposing restraints that trap a system in a local free energy minimum, and thereby prevent the system from transitioning to a global free energy minimum.